# The pcmanfm-qt is dead on my Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: lubuntu, qt, pcmanfm

I know it is so weird, but last night I set an image on my desktop background and delete the image, then I right-click on the desktop and press the `desktop properties` to change the style of background (center, stretch and etc) then the `desktop properties` stopped something like hanging on Windows.

Then a black window alerted something and I press `yes` without reading it. after that with right-click on the desktop I just see this:

[image]

Even some system applications don't work now. for example, I cannot take a screenshot.

Also, my `pcmanfm-qt` is dead completely, with the command line or clicking on the icon nothing happens.

I don't know what happens. and I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: This looks like the default graphical session was somehow changed. Now it is a plain OpenBox. You have to logout and then select LUbuntu  or LxQt on login screen.

Comment: Dear @N0rbert, I did it several times. but nothing happens. Even I remove and re-install `pcmanfm-qt`. but still, it doesn't make sense. weird. really weird. I have not any of these problems with Lubuntu LXDE 18.04. I guess I should remove and re-install thee LXDE.

Comment: `pcmanfm-qt` does handle the background & much of the window for LXQt... If it crashed, there should be a .crash file in /var/crash/ so please look and `ubuntu-bug` that crash report if found (with description of what you did of course too).  If it's hanging (waiting for your image) there won't be a crash file. If it's the wallpaper change as you said, change your wallpaper by editing `~/.config/pcmanfm-qt/lxqt/settings.conf` to point to a different file  (the "Wallpaper=" line).

Comment: If the Wallpaper= line fixes it, it may still be worthwhile filing it as a bug, as I'll confirm it myself & look further. I would file using `ubuntu-bug lubuntu-default-settings` and please describe what you did & what fixed it, as it'll likely impact other users too and thus should be fixed (bug filed upstream after the confirmation)

Comment: Dear @guiverc, changing the inexistent image address in the `~/.config/pcmanfm-qt/lxqt/settings.conf` makes everything to work. it is a really bad bug. furthermore, I have a question. on Stack Overflow the pro users leave answers but here someone professional like just leaves comments instead of an answer. please post an answer. your guidance help me to get back on track everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pcmanfm-qt` does handle the background & much of the window for LXQt...

As you suggested it's the wallpaper change, change your wallpaper by editing

```
~/.config/pcmanfm-qt/lxqt/settings.conf
```

to point to a different file (change the `Wallpaper=` line)

Comment: If you'd like to file the bug as I described earlier in comments, that would be appreciated. I'll endeavour to test for this issue this arvo & file a bug if I don't notice one reported on #ubuntu-bugs-announce (irc) in the next couple of hours.

Comment: Please post another answer, to how I file the bug. the Lubuntu LXQt in on a good way but have many bugs. we should help to fix. thanks.

Comment: Open a terminal and enter `ubuntu-bug lubuntu-default-settings`... It'll cause some details of your system to be grabbed, (release info, kernel, package versions) etc & will cause your default browser (firefox unless changed) to be opened where you can login to launchpad.net (Ubuntu's bug tracker) and you can enter details.. For detailed info on reporting bugs please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and for Lubuntu package clues on what to file against (ie. package name for `ubuntu-bug`) see https://phab.lubuntu.me/w/bugs/