# How to fix black desktop in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, openbox, lxpanel

I'm using Lubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa), When I tried to change my background image, window and the desktop got froze so I thought it would be a good idea to logout, but the desktop was black when I logged in.
every other app except File manager (`pcmanfm-qt`) works fine and printscreen shortcut key didn't work but other shortcut keys works normally.

This black desktop got a different menu but totally useless.
[image]

I don't understand what happened and how to fix it.
I have tried reinstalling `lubuntu-desktop` and remove `~/.config/openbox` folder.

found same problem at [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1144623/853862), but I can't open Desktop settings

Comment: What theme did you use?

Comment: I use Arc-Darker, @Levente
I can change themes without any problem

Comment: And you mean the problem persists even after changing themes?

Comment: yes @Levente, I can change Appearance and Openbox settings. but Desktop settings won't open.

Comment: I believe this has been noted before on this site, and I could re-produce it and thus filed a bug; I also think I had a workaround (I replicated the bug in debian for confirmation it wasn't a Lubuntu only bug, but LXQt and sure didn't re-install my debian).. I'll look for details, however you've tagged LXDE & `lxpanel`, neither of which are used by Lubuntu 20.04 LTS or LXQt, so is your system standard? Your screen shows `lxqt-panel` and **not** `lxpanel`  (FYI: it's a config issue which isn't impacted by re-install of lxqt packages; but editing conf file & reversing your change will fix)

Comment: Your description on re-read doesn't fit what my first comment was talking about (it was a config change that caused `pcmanfm-qt` to end up in a loop & be incapable of responding...  (`pcmanfm-qt` isn't just a *file-manager* but also handles the desktop itself including wallpaper etc) I suspect now your issue is you upgraded from LXDE and didn't re-install....

Comment: @guiverc you are right. it is `lxqt-panel` and `pcmanfm-qt` looks stuck in a loop. it took 50% of cpu usage. I just install this from iso 7 days ago. but still I don't know how to reversing my changes on config file to fix the problem.

Comment: It reminds me of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pcmanfm-qt/+bug/1878336 or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238736/the-pcmanfm-qt-is-dead-on-my-lubuntu-20-04 but there is no reference to `lxsession-default` (LXDE) there..  I booted a QA-test install of 20.04.2 and haven't found no references to `lxsession` anywhere; but correcting your incorrect tags would be helpful (it implies upgrade and not fresh install which left many LXDE issues; wrong pointers to non-existent software). FYI: The *fix released* really applied to *groovy*

Comment: I deleted config files of `pcmanfm-qt` and everything went back to normal. thank you @guiverc

Comment: `lubuntu-default-setings` package /usr/share/lubuntu//openbox/rc,xml` & `menu.xml` contains the 'lxsession-default` links in your error message

Comment: @guiverc I know error message shows about openbox, but problem was at `pcmanfm-qt` and thank you for inform about it. yes @karel answer is from https://askubuntu.com/q/1238736/853862 but my config file seems normal to me, I just removed it and restarted because I could not find any problem.